# JavaFX: Weird ClassNotFoundException after updating to Java 9

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, java-9, javafx-9

I started a Maven project in Java 8 and wanted to migrate it to Java 9. At the same time I also went from Eclipse Neon EE to Eclipse Oxygen EE. (JFX SDK reinstalled).
While the Eclipse Workspace shows no errors; as soon as I try to compile and run the exact same program that used to run perfectly fine in Java 8, I get the following Exception:

```
{...}
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.css.converters.PaintConverter
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
... 26 more
```

Exception running application application.Main

I have now rebuilt the project several times and cannot get it to work...

Comment: Update: I am using JFoenix in my project, which seems to require the com.sun.javafx.css.converters.PaintConverter class in some classes like the JFXTextField. Is it possible, that said package has been removed with Java 9 for some reason? And if so, do I have no choice but going back to Java 8? (Just downgraded it and works fine again)

Comment: google the package name and 'java 9' for the details.

Comment: @pvg Yeah, thanks for nothing. I totally didn't have that idea 2 days ago

Comment: A pleasure, glad you found the answer 2 days ago!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In Java 9**, the previous internal class

```
com.sun.javafx.css.converters.PaintConverter
```

became public as

`javafx.css.converter.PaintConverter` in the module `javafx.graphics`.

See [Javadoc - *Class PaintConverter*](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/javafx/css/converter/PaintConverter.html).

[JFoenix](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix) supports Java 9 with a [separate JAR](http://www.jfoenix.com/download/jfoenix-9.0.0.jar).

Comment: If JFoenix is indeed using the internal com.sun class directly then someone should submit a bug to the project to make them aware of the supported/public API.

Comment: @AlanBateman JFoenix has already created its own version for Java 9 (see my extended answer).