# JFoenix incorporation with Eclipse

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, jfoenix

I have been trying to use Jfoenix for quite some time now on eclipse but it never seems to work. I would really appreciate if any one here could help me. My JDK is 12.02, SceneBuilder Version is 8.5.0, Eclipse 2019-12, java version 8 update 261 in addition to JFoenix 8.0.10. I have all the paths figured out it simply just doesn't run. I can run the application without the JFoenix Libraries but I need my application to be aesthetically pleasing.
Here are the errors:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/css/converters/PaintConverter
    at com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField$StyleableProperties.<clinit>(JFXTextField.java:241)
    at com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField.<init>(JFXTextField.java:146)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:166)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:404)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:590)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1019)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:754)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.javafx.css.converters.PaintConverter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 30 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/HomePage.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,1000,800);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The code ^

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPasswordField?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.Cursor?>
<?import javafx.scene.Group?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<StackPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controllers.HomePageLoginController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="644.0" prefWidth="940.0" style="-fx-background-color: #8ED5FF;">
         <children>
            <AnchorPane layoutX="394.0" layoutY="7.0" prefHeight="630.0" prefWidth="529.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FFFF; -fx-background-radius: 10px;">
               <effect>
                  <DropShadow color="#0617b5" />
               </effect>
               <children>
                  <TabPane fx:id="tabPane" layoutX="1.0" layoutY="100.0" prefHeight="483.0" prefWidth="528.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
                    <tabs>
                      <Tab fx:id="employeeTab" text="Employee">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <JFXTextField fx:id="employeeUsernameText" focusColor="#1357cf" labelFloat="true" layoutX="125.0" layoutY="138.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="304.0" promptText="Employee Username" unFocusColor="#4d4d4d">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="Constantia Bold" size="19.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </JFXTextField>
                                    <JFXPasswordField fx:id="EmployeePasswordTab" focusColor="#1357cf" labelFloat="true" layoutX="126.0" layoutY="215.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="304.0" promptText="Employee Password">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="Constantia Bold" size="19.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </JFXPasswordField>
                                    <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="21.0" layoutY="400.0" prefHeight="21.0" prefWidth="469.0" text="Welcome Label">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="Constantia Italic" size="15.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </Label>
                                    <JFXButton fx:id="employeeLogin" layoutX="217.0" layoutY="303.0" style="-fx-background-color: #8ED5FF; -fx-background-radius: 10px;" text="Login">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="Constantia Bold" size="19.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </JFXButton>
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                        </Tab>
                      <Tab fx:id="tabClient" text="Client">
                           <content>
                              <AnchorPane prefHeight="432.0" prefWidth="528.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <JFXTextField fx:id="clientUsernameText" focusColor="#1357cf" labelFloat="true" layoutX="125.0" layoutY="138.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="304.0" promptText="Client Username" unFocusColor="#4d4d4d">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="Constantia Bold" size="19.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </JFXTextField>
                                    <JFXPasswordField fx:id="clientPasswordText" focusColor="#1357cf" labelFloat="true" layoutX="126.0" layoutY="215.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="304.0" promptText="Client Password">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="Constantia Bold" size="19.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </JFXPasswordField>
                                    <JFXButton fx:id="clientLoginButton" layoutX="224.0" layoutY="305.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="89.0" style="-fx-background-color: #8ED5FF; -fx-background-radius: 10px;" text="Login">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="Constantia Bold" size="18.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </JFXButton>
                                    <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" layoutX="21.0" layoutY="400.0" prefHeight="21.0" prefWidth="469.0" text="Welcome Label Client">
                                       <font>
                                          <Font name="Constantia Italic" size="15.0" />
                                       </font>
                                    </Label>
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                           </content>
                        </Tab>
                    </tabs>
                  </TabPane>
                  <Group layoutX="68.0" layoutY="47.0">
                     <children>
                        <Pane fx:id="slidingPane" layoutX="6.0" layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="368.0">
                           <children>
                              <Label fx:id="employeeStatus" alignment="CENTER" onMouseClicked="#openEmployee" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="158.0" style="-fx-font-weight: 700;" text="EMPLOYEE" textAlignment="CENTER">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                              <Label fx:id="clientLabelStatus" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="174.0" layoutY="-1.0" onMouseClicked="#openClient" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="197.0" style="-fx-font-weight: 700;" text="CLIENT" textAlignment="CENTER">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                           </children>
                        </Pane>
                        <Label fx:id="labelStatus" alignment="CENTER" layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="167.0" style="-fx-background-color: #8ED5FF; -fx-background-radius: 10px;" text="EMPLOYEE">
                           <cursor>
                              <Cursor fx:constant="DEFAULT" />
                           </cursor>
                        </Label>
                     </children>
                  </Group>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane layoutX="41.0" layoutY="132.0">
               <children>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="353.0" fitWidth="414.0" layoutX="-25.0" layoutY="10.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@../../../../Downloads/imageedit_1_7896082891.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </children>
               <effect>
                  <DropShadow color="WHITE" />
               </effect>
            </AnchorPane>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</StackPane>
```

The FXML doc ^
Please help

Comment: I think this problem is related to the java version used, try to see this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46754639/javafx-weird-classnotfoundexception-after-updating-to-java-9) and this link (https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/issues/523)

Comment: I'm using version 8 is that the issue? No my java version seems fine from the documents you've linked

Comment: as shown in the second link : "If you're using Java 8, make sure you have version above 1.8.0_60"

Comment: Yepp Im using 1.8.0_261

Comment: You wrote in your question: _All my versions of Java, JavaFX, SceneBuilder and eclipse are up to date_ What does that mean? Are you using JDK 14.0.2, which is the latest public release? Are you using JavaFX 14, which is the latest version? Are you using ScenBuilder for Java 11? Are you using Eclipse 2020-06? And don't post images of the stack trace, post the actual text. Is taking a screen capture easier than doing a copy/paste?

Comment: My bad Abra, My JDK is 12.02, SceneBuilder Version is 8.5.0, Eclipse 2019-12

Comment: I recommend that you [edit] your question and add the versions of JDK and JavaFX that you are using.